# How is the CONTENT_TYPE attribute populated in attachment tables in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, attachments

When you enable attachments on a table or feature class, there are a number of fields that get created in the attachment table.
`ATTACHMETNID, REL_GLOBALID, CONTENT_TYPE, ATT_NAME, DATA_SIZE, DATA, GLOBALID`.

In the table I'm looking at, the CONTENT_TYPE field has values such as:

```
image/jpg 
image/tiff
image/png 
image/xls
application/zip 
application/msword    
video/quicktime
```

It looks like for images, ArcGIS automatically just puts the word image and the extension. Also, if it doesn't know what it is, it just calls it an image (xls in the example above).

What I would like to know, is if there is a list of all possible values that can be stored in the CONTENT_TYPE field. I'm building an integration and will need to map these values to other values.